# cast from [UICollectionViewCell] to unrelated type 'profileviewCell' as always

Tags: ios, swift

1) I write a profileViewCell.swift that is point to UICollectionViewCell 
2) I write a profileViewController.swift is point to all UICollectionViewDelegates

when i try to add a code in viewDidLoad method like this

NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: Selector("resetView"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

3) in resetView method i can call a collection view sell first object like this

func resetView(){

```
    let cell:profileViewCell = self.collectionView.visibleCells() as! profileViewCell
    self.reset(cell)

}
```

then a complier shows a error& warning like "cast from [UICollectionViewCell] to unrelated type 'profileviewCell' as always" please help me in this kind , thanks in advance

Comment: As @Wain states you will get many cells in the visibleCells call. Loop through them if you want to perform some action. You could use `map`, or one of its variants or any for/while/repeat loop. Don't forget to up vote and accept his answer if it helps you. Doing so will encourage others to answer your future questions on the site. BTW - Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `visibleCells` returns an array of cells, but you're trying to cast it to and use it as a single cell - you can't do that. You either need to take one cell from the array to work with or iterate over them all.

Comment: can i use visibleCells.first instead without looping them

Comment: sure, that will compile and run